# QML: wait until animations finished

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to make visible animations sequential. I have a javascript function, which call myModel.move() two times. I have a GridView to show myModel and I have "Behavior on x" animation, thus I can visualy see the movements. But, both movement animatons runs in paralell (the small delay between them is not noticeable).

My idea was to add a counter of how many animations was started and how many of them already finished. Something like this;

```
Behavior on x {
    NumberAnimation {
        id: animationX;
        duration: 500;
        onRunningChanged: {
            if (animationX.running) {
                console.log("Animation start");
                myModel.busy = myModel.busy + 1
            } else {
                console.log("Animation stop");
                myModel.busy = myModel.busy - 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works as expected. Then, I add a loop to my javascript function to wait until all the animations finished.

```
ListModel {
    id: myModel
    property int busy: 0
    function doSomething() {
        myModel.move(...)
        while (myModel.busy) {}
        myModel.move(...)
    }
}
```

Here is the problem. I can see that after the first move() all neccessary animations started, but nothing can be seen and none of the animation finished. I have some kind of a deadlock. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution based on the answer from #UmNyobe. Well, QML is a declarative language and thus problematic for iterative problems. Any comments are welcomed. Maybe, someone can suggest better (more readable) pure QML program which will produce the same effect.

```
import QtQuick 1.1
GridView {
    id: mainGrid
    cellWidth: 165; cellHeight: 95
    width: 5*cellWidth; height: 4*cellHeight
    model: myModel
    delegate: myButton
    property string animate: "no"
    property int busy: 0
    signal busyPlus
    signal busyMinus
    onBusyPlus: {
        busy++
    }
    onBusyMinus: {
        busy--
        if (busy == 0) mainGrid.model.algorithm()
    }
    ListModel {
        id: myModel
        property int step: 0
        property int one: 0
        function createModel() {
            for (var i=1; i<=20; i++) {
                append({"display": i})
            }
        }
        function algorithm() {
            if (step == 0) {
                move(0,19,1)
                one = 0
                step++
            }
            else if (step == 1) {
                if (one < 19) {
                    move(one,one+1,1)
                    one++
                    if (one == 19) step++
                }
            }
            else if (step == 2) {
                move(0,1,1)
                move(5,6,1)
                move(10,11,1)
                move(15,16,1)
                step++
            }
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            createModel()
            mainGrid.animate = "yes"
            algorithm()
        }
    }
    Component {
        id: myButton
        Item {
            id: item
            width: mainGrid.cellWidth-5; height: mainGrid.cellHeight-5;
            Rectangle {
                id: box
                parent: mainGrid
                x: item.x; y: item.y;
                width: item.width; height: item.height;
                border.width: 1
                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: display
                    font.pixelSize: 48
                }
                Behavior on x {
                    enabled: mainGrid.animate == "yes"
                    NumberAnimation {
                        id: animationX;
                        duration: 1000;
                        onRunningChanged: {
                            if (animationX.running) mainGrid.busyPlus()
                            else mainGrid.busyMinus()
                        }
                    }
                }
                Behavior on y {
                    enabled: mainGrid.animate == "yes"
                    NumberAnimation {
                        id: animationY;
                        duration: 1000;
                        onRunningChanged: {
                            if (animationY.running) mainGrid.busyPlus()
                            else mainGrid.busyMinus()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function doSomething() {
    myModel.move(...)
    while (myModel.busy) {}
    myModel.move(...)
}
```

I am not good with javascript. But why do you busy loop? I would create 2 functions.

- The first one make `myModel.move()`, then prepare the field for a future event (like creating a hidden button which will be clicked)
- The second one will be called when the the future event is created. With the example above it will be `Onclick`.

It seems that `onRunningChanged` is a definition of event handler. Why not creating the same , lets call it `onModelIdle` like

```
...
   onRunningChanged: {
        if (animationX.running) {
            console.log("Animation start");
            myModel.busy = myModel.busy + 1
        } else {
            console.log("Animation stop");
            myModel.busy = myModel.busy - 1
            if(myModel.busy == 0)
              // don't know the code, but trigger the onModelIdle event which 
              // be handled below
        }
    }
...

ListModel {
   id: myModel
   ...

   onModelIdle{
       myModel.move(...)
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know ... simplified questions produce simplified answers :-( In fact, I want to have many different consecutive myModel.move(...) calls. However, your suggestion is usable (see the solution I posted below).

Comment: A busy loop isn't a good idea if you want to maintain performance.

Comment: @UmNyobe Nowhere, so added for future stumblers. :} I might add that in browsers you can create graphically performant loops using requestAnimationFrame. Qt Quick also has an equivalent version of the function, which when used wisely to create loops will lead to better performance of graphical animations: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html#requestAnimationFrame-method A busy loop in a non-graphical thread is perfectly fine for crunching numbers as fast as possible (rather than limiting the loop to 16ms ticks as you do with requestAnimationFrame). So, it depends on the use case. :)